# How to avoid processing files that have already been processed during previous runs?

Tags: shell-script, files

Here is a script which modifies all the files in a defined path:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/files/*
for f in $FILES
do
  [some_command_to_make_changes_into_file] $f > tmp_$f; mv tmp_$f $f
done
```

The code is working fine for the first run; the problem is when I run this script a second or third time, it again picks all the files. How can I  **not process** all those files which have already been processed in the previous run? I can't change filenames or path.

Comment: Try creating an array with all the files that have been processed and then check against that array on subsequent runs.

Comment: @RamanSailopal and where would the array be stored? The OP wants each run if the script to know what a previous one did. Serenesat, you will need to use a log file, there's no way a script can know what a previous instance of itself did.

Comment: easy way is add an specific part of your files name to your `FILES=/path/to/files/*` line like `FILES=/path/to/files/myfiles*` then within loop rename the files to something like `processed_myfile....`, then next time it will not take those files, Or another way is move them to another path. EDIT: this is what [AnFi;s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398798/72456) did :  )

Comment: I'd agree with tredon's remark about creating a log file. You could just write into one file which files/filepaths have been already processed and check against that before running your modifcations again. Would only be 1 file and no need to create some kind of extra directory with hundreds of files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "processed" mark-file(s).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
TAG="done"
FILES=/path/to/files/*
for f in $FILES
do
  case "$f" in
    *.$TAG) # process mark-files
      echo "# TAG-FILE=$f"
      b=`echo $f | sed "s/\.$TAG\$//"` # get base file of the mark-file
      echo "#   FILE=$b"
      if [ ! -f "$b" ] ; then
        echo "#  TAG-FILE REMOVE" 
        rm $f # remove mark-file without base file
      file
      continue # do not process mark-files themselves
      ;; 
  esac
  if [ -f "$f.TAG" ] ; then
    echo "# FILE=$f"
    echo "#   TAG-FILE PRESENT"
    continue # mark-file present - skip processing
  fi
  echo "# FILE=$f"
  echo "#   TAG-FILE ABSENT => PROCESSING"


  # [some_command_to_make_changes_into_file] $f > tmp_$f; mv tmp_$f $f

  echo "#   PROCESSED"
  touch "$f.$TAG" # create mark-file
  if [ -f "$f.TAG" ] ; then
    echo "#   TAG-FILE CREATED"
  else
    echo "#   TAG-FILE CREATION FAILED!"
    exit
  fi
done
```

*Possible improvement:* You can store mark-files in another directory.

Comment: I can see the time change for all the files in a second or third run. Is it processing all the file but not making any changes in mark-file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a modern filesystem like `ext4`,`btrfs`, `xfs` etc you could take advantage of the [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) - in this case you could use a "user" namespace attribute. So, check each file for that particular attribute - if it's set<sup>1</sup> then skip the file, otherwise process the file *then* set the attribute. Let's say the attribute and its value was defined as

```
user.validation="processed"
```

then your code could do something like this:

```sh
for f in /path/to/files/*
  do
    if ! getfattr -n user.validation "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1
      then
        echo "$f"
        setfattr -n user.validation -v processed "$f"
    fi
  done
```

Replace `echo` with your commands... Also, note the proper way to loop over the result of glob expansion - either use the glob with `for` or save the result in an array and iterate over its elements:

```
filez=( /path/to/files/* )
for f in "${filez[@]}"
```

---

<sup>1: for the sake of simplicity the script only checks if the attribute is set - it does not check its value.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That could be a good case to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), etc...

For example, given some `foo.txt` input file, you could either decide to put its transformation in `foo.out` or `touch`  some `foo.done`  empty mark file  (see [Anfi's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398798/50557)), and have rules in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)  for all that. BTW, these mark (or log) files could sit in some other directory.

GNU `make`  (and `ninja`, etc...) can be used not only to compile things, but more generally to trigger processing based on file timestamps (if you adopt some conventions).

And with `make -j 4`  you would have up to four tasks in parallel to do that processing, so you would probably wait less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use make to create "processed" mark-file(s) in another directory.

```makefile
# version for gnu-make

# Path to directory with jobs files
DIR_JOBS=/path/to/files
# Path to directory with mark files marking processes job files
DIR_MARKS=/path/to/mark-files

JOBS=$(wildcard $(DIR_JOBS)/*)
MARKS=$(wildcard $(DIR_MARKS)/*)
JOBS_MARKS=$(patsubst $(DIR_JOBS)/%,$(DIR_MARKS)/%.done, $(JOBS))

$(DIR_MARKS)/%.done: $(DIR_JOBS)/%
        @echo '###' make $@ from $<
        # your command to process the job file - should return 0 on success
        touch $@

ALL: $(JOBS_MARKS)
        @echo '###' for debug purposes
        @echo JOBS=$(JOBS)
        @echo JOBS_MARKS=$(JOBS_MARKS)
        @echo MARKS=$(MARKS
```